# PowerBI - x-axis month label sorting

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm creating a line chart in PowerBi for NPS where the line legend is the year and the x-axi label is the first initial of the month. I'm having a dilemma in sorting the month initial. Can someone assist on this? thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: How have you extracted the first character of each month? Do you want to sort the months chronologically?

Comment: Yes.  @norie I created a new fields call CallDateMonthInitial. In SSRS platfrom i can do a layers of sort by, but not sure how to do it in PowerBI. (newbie in PowerBi). Trying to mimic a line chart that i have in Tableau and SSRS. Thanks,

Comment: If you still have the date field you derived the x-axis values from you could sort the x-axis by that field via Sort by Column from the Column tools tab.

Comment: I decided to just use the Original date field and drag it to create a hierarchy and it automatically got sorted.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to sort.

The first one is on graph level, meaning that you will only sort one specific graph:

[image: Sort on graph]

Steps:

- Click on the graph you want to sort
- Click on the three dots
- Click 'sort'(In my example named 'Sorteren op')
- Choose what you want to sort on.

However, this will most likely not provide you with the right solution. Since it is already sorted on date letter, but in alphabetical order.

Therefore the second solution, sort on colum.

[image: Panes]

First, we go to the data tab (Or columns tab).
In my example, I have opened a date table to match your question.
Here I select the 'MonthShort' (MaandKort) because I want it sorted based on a number instead of on letters.

Sort on column:
[image: Sort on column]

Sort on column select:
[image: Sort on column select]

If you click the column, it automatically opens the 'kolomhulpmiddelen' tab. Here you can select the 'sort on column' pane and click on the column you want to sort on.

In my case, I chose the monthnumber. So from now on, if I use the MonthShort in a graph, it will sort it based on the monthnumber, meaning that I will see Jan - Feb - Mar etc.

***Note***: This is from the Dutch version of Power BI.